# Cloud Run does not response but the script is working

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-cloud-run

I'm running a pipeline using cloud run. The code work as in test and on cloud run (the data was then loaded to bigquery so I can confirm this). However, after the code is executed, cloud run does not return any response back and keep running till timeout (which raised an error to cloud tasks).

here is my code example

```
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  Joi.object<RequestBody>({
    //some variables with Joi validation
  })
    .validateAsync(req.body)
    .then(async (variables ) => {
      return runPipeline(variables)
        .then((result) => {
          res.status(200).json({ result });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          res.status(500).json({ error }); 
        });
    }).then(
      (result) => res.status(200).json({result})
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error });
    });
});
```

I tried to use res.status to send responses back after the code is done, however it does not work

Comment: Can you share the error message? Also have a look at this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#timeout-504)

Comment: It does not raise any error, the script executed, and the data was loaded into BQ, but it does not seem to return anything.
I've used postman to test bet postman stuck at "sending request" screen

Comment: I used cloud task to send multiple requests as well and they also retry as the script runs till timed out

Comment: Can you try checking the cloud run logs by following this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging).

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to run the code myself, I can't say for sure, but I think the nested promises aren't returning the result to the following `.then` method. If you want to keep the nested promise, I think the `result` probably needs to be returned:

```
// Option 1 (minor changes, but still a little hard to read.)
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  Joi.object<RequestBody>({
    //some variables with Joi validation
  })
    .validateAsync(req.body)
    .then(async (variables ) => {
      return runPipeline(variables)
        .then((result) => {
          return result;
        })
    }).then(
      (result) => res.status(200).json({result})
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error });
    });
});
```

Since you're using `async` already, I'm wondering if you're ok with a slight refactor? I think something like this might make it easier to read and debug:

```
// Option 2 (more changes, but easier to read.)
app.use("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const variables = await Joi.object<RequestBody>({
      //some variables with Joi validation
    }).validateAsync(req.body);
    const result = runPipeline(variables);
    return res.status(200).json({ result });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your approach but it hasn't solved the problem.
I ran the code on local server & used Postman to test if it works => It works.
But on the deployed version on cloud run does not run as expected. So I think the code was not the problem but the docker & yml file. Tks for your help

Comment: update: I ran the docker file on local and it still works

Comment: Interesting. I don’t know that I can help without more details. Are you able to share more information like your logs or repository?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason was that I called `createWriteStream` at a high freq so it was not executed as expected.
I dived deeper into the log and found that a subset of rows was loaded into BQ tables (e.g. 96/215 rows). The rest stay still in a waiting line with large deadline, that's why the script does not raise DeadlineExceeded error until the task reached dispatchDeadline.

documentation: [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-best-practices#limit_the_rate_of_stream_creation)

[image: Notice by Google Team]